# Integrating factor in differential equation

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

We are given a differential equation which involves a integrating factor.  the equation is:

$$\frac{d I}{d\cos\theta } = \frac{1+ \cos \theta}{1+\sin^2\theta}$$

The way I understand to do integration from above equation: $$\int dI =  \int    \  d\cos\theta  \ \Bigg(\frac{1+ \cos \theta}{1+\sin^2\theta}\Bigg)$$

**But I have seen it has been written in this way:**

I did not understand if we can write  the term ($\frac{1+ \cos \theta}{1+\sin^2\theta}$) as integrating factor like this:

$$\frac{\int \ d\cos \theta  \  (1+ \cos \theta)}{\int d \cos  \ \theta \ (1+\sin^2\theta)}$$

Comment: The last line is a bit ambiguous; some parenthesis would be helpful.

Comment: $d\cos\theta$ is $-\sin\theta d\theta$, You have an extra $d\theta$ in your second equation.

Comment: Thanks,@Nikunj. Fixed that.

Comment: The notation is the thesis is not clear (at least to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot rewrite the integral in that way.

You can simplify the integrals a little by putting $\  x=cos\theta\ $.  Then $\ 1+\sin^2\theta=2-x^2\ $, and your first integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1+x}{2-x^2}dx&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-x}\right)dx+\int\frac{x}{2-x^2}dx\\
&= \frac{\ln(|\sqrt{2}+x|)-\ln(|\sqrt{2}-x|)}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\ln(|2-x^2|)}{2}+C\ ,
\end{align}
whereas the second is
\begin{align}
\frac{\int(1+x)dx}{\int(2-x^2)dx}=\frac{6x+3x^2+C_1}{12x-2x^3+C_2}\ .
\end{align}
**P.S.** I have here interpreted the expression $\ \displaystyle\int d\cos\theta f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\ $ as being synonymous with $\ \displaystyle\int \frac{d\cos\theta}{d\theta} f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) d\theta\ $.  Evidently the OP's source was a physics thesis whose intended meaning *could* be something else, although I'm not aware of any other reasonably obvious candidate.

Comment: Could you have a look in the equation (1.100) in page number  in page number 31. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/157744129.pdf  ?  I  just wanted to make sure I did not misunderstood the jargon I wrote here and what I have seen in the thesis.

If you think different, I will update the question according to your suggestions.

Comment: Equation $(1.100)$ is (in part)
$$
\tilde{D}_{\cos2\phi}=\frac{\displaystyle\int d\cos\theta\sin^2\theta}{\displaystyle\int d\cos\theta\left(1+\cos^2\theta\right)}\ .
$$
As far as I could see, the thesis containing the equation does not explicitly give limits for the ranges of integration, but does say that the ratio of the integrals evaluates to $\ \frac{2/3}{4/3}\ $. This would be the value of the ratio if my interpretation of the notation is correct, and the ranges of the integrals were from $\ -\frac{\pi}{2}\ $ to  $\ 0\ $.

Comment: You are right. The limit of the integration is in polar coordinates, which can be from $0  $ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: Using the substitution $\ \cos\theta=x\ $ the ratio then becomes
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^1 \left(1-x^2\right)dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^1 \left(1+x^2\right)dx}\ .
$$
Again, as far as I can see, the thesis nowhere equates this ratio of integrals to the integral $\ \displaystyle\int d\cos\theta\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta}{1+\cos^2\theta}\right) $, which would certainly be an error if my interpretation of the notation is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept you answer and look more into this if they actually made any notations error.